# What file is needed for webRTC AEC for android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webrtc

I wand to add webRTC files to android studio and want to do AEC.
but there are too many files in webRTC..
I have already tried many files from git but failed.
for example
https://github.com/thepacific/webrtc-android-jni

https://github.com/DoubangoTelecom/webrtc-audioproc

could anyone define what file should i add to android studio?

error is below

> Error:instruction not supported on mips32r6 or mips64r6
>   Error:error: instruction requires a CPU feature not currently enabled

I tried deleting files about mips and neon but it also didn't work..

please help me!!

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1):

I just did this myself.

The WebRTC project is pretty interconnected. The best solution is to build the entire project for Android (You require a linux machine for this) using their GN build system, which will result in a libwebrtc.a library.

You'll then need to write a JNI wrapper over the AudioProcessing module (https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/modules/audio_processing/include/audio_processing.h).

The company I work for, Frozen Mountain, offers a product called IceLink (https://www.frozenmountain.com/products-services/icelink/) that offers a complete WebRTC solution for Android if you want to go that route.